# I can't figure out the bug in this jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firebug

The page having problems is...
http://schnell.dreamhosters.com/index.php?page=gallery#

I use Firebug to debug my jQuery and other code tidbits and it's been proving very useful for Javascript/jQuery debugging.  However, at the same time, it's been one of the most frustrating debugging experiences I've ever gone through.  I'm not sure why but sometimes it seems like I can copy someone else's methodology from a tutorial, character for character, and yet still come up with errors.

In any case, the problem here is that Firebug claims there is a bug on line 20 of the source.

missing : after property id
[Break on this error] $('#table').animate({"left: " + attr + "px"}, 2000);\n

This bug seems like a huge load to me because the colon **is right there**!  And this is why debugging jQuery/Javascript is such a pain sometimes.  The error messages are rather convoluted and sometimes don't even make a lick of sense to me. Or maybe that's just Firebug.

Either way, the goal I'm going for here is that I'm trying to dynamically change the animate function such that the more you click the left arrow, the further left the grid of images is shifted (due to the nature of the CSS 'left' property).  I have Javascript variables and a hidden input tag to help hold essential values, but the major hurdle is getting the animate function to recognize these variables.  Near as I can tell it will only accept string literals for arguments on how to animate and the documentation doesn't help me because it doesn't discuss the use of variables with animate, as if it's impossible.

Well, let's just say I don't like impossible, he likes to get in my way a lot.

Comment: I've run into another bug, this one a functional bug.

If I scroll through my grid of pictures and build the var 'count' up to, say, 6 and then refresh the page, count will still be at 6.  So the next time I go to click the arrow, the grid moves 7 steps (6 + 1) to the right instead of starting over again.  Since I cap the steps at 11 (the end of the grid), it gets to a point that you can't scroll through the grid at all because it thinks you are already at the end and can't move any further.  The only way I've found to clear the variable is by closing the tab and revisiting the site.  Advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object literal passed to the animate function is not well formed, it should be:

```
$('#table').animate({left: attr + "px"}, 2000);
```

**Edit**: Looking closely to your code, you are also trying to get a value from an input with id = "count", and you have a missing # character to have an ID selector:

```
var count = +$('#count').val(); // get #count value as Number
```

You are also incrementing this `count` variable, but you should first convert it to Number, because  the `value` attribute of `input` elements are string. (*I did it using the unary plus operator on the right-hand side of the assignment*).

You have to convert it to a number, because if you *add* two variables and one of them is a string, concatenation will take place:

```
 "1" + 1 == "11"
```

Comment: I don't quite understand why that is valid and what I was doing is not, but Firebug isn't yelling at me anymore so it's a victory in my book.  Now to see if the whole mess will do what I want it to.

Comment: Also thank you for pointing out those errors.  I didn't realize the value attribute from an input tag was a string by default and I had assumed that vars in JS are similar to the PHP $ variables in that the most appropriate datatype is chosen for the variable upon initilization

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#table').animate({left: attr}, 2000);
```

The "px" units of measurement here aren't necessary. That aside, the above is the correct creation of an anonymous object. You were just putting a string inside curly braces.

Comment: It's strange because I've seen code where the what is passed into the animation function is an entire string literal, such as

"top: 300px" 

and yet with the way this is behaving it's more like 

top: "300px"

Maybe what I've seen is an old style that is no longer considered valid or jQuery is just really picky.

Comment: You might see: animate("{left: 20}", 3000) but that's different.